# Get value from input text box and show value into another

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get value from 1st input and show same value in a 2nd input
But value is not showed in 2nd taxt box.
Where I'm wrong?

Thanks a lot.

```
<div class="rowElem"><label>COGS:<span class="req">*</span></label><div class="formRight"><input type="text" name="cogs" id="cogs" value="<?=$_POST[cogs]?>" onchange="run(cogs)/></div><div class="fix"></div></div>


    <script>
                    function cogs(sel) {
                        var name=document.form1.cogs.value;
                    }
            </script>

<div class="rowElem"><label>COGS:<span class="req">*</span></label><div class="formRight"><input type="text" name="cogs" id="cogs" value="cogs"/></div><div class="fix"></div></div>
```

Comment: Your function cogs() does not return any value nor does it change any element. It simply assigns a value to the variable `name`.

Comment: not exaclty an answer, but multiple elements with the same is is forbidden, just for the record.

Comment: yes and in your input you call function runs and you have defined function as cogs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have an example about how to assing the value of a input to another

```
<input type="text" name="cogs1" id="cogs1" value="<?=$_POST[cogs]?>" 
     onchange="cogs(this.value)"/>
<input type="text" name="cogs2" id="cogs2" value="cogs"/>

<script>
    function cogs(value) {
        document.getElementById("cogs2").value = value;
    }
</script>
```