# Random text value from Input text and display in another input text

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble with get random text from other input text value like this.

when user write name

```
<input type="text" name="txtuser" onchange="getalias(this)">
```

and user outomaticly get the alias

```
<input id="alias" type="text" name="txtalias">
```

onchange code

```
<script>
function getalias() {
...    
}
</script>
```

and the result is like this

```
name : riski
alias: rki_ (or other)
```

can anyone give me a example how to random value from "txtuser" and display in alias input text.

Comment: It's really unclear what you need please edit your question.

Comment: by alias you mean 'name' ?

Comment: sory, i already edit my question for clear.

Comment: Do you want to generate a random string a certain length?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833340/get-value-from-input-text-box-and-show-value-into-another

Comment: @squint yes like that but not same value but random words from same value limit 3 or 4 words

Comment: so if I understood corectly, you want to be able to generate an alias for a username. does it have to follow certain rules? like it should start with the same letter? same length?

Comment: @StefanBaiu yes same latter or same value and random the value with limit length. like 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length,
    temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}

function getalias(that) {
  var val = that.value;
  var alias = '';
  var splitVal = val.split('');
  var shuffled = shuffle(splitVal);
  for (var i = 0, len = shuffled.length; i < len; i++) {


    alias += shuffled[i];
  }
  document.getElementById('alias').value = alias;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="txtuser" onkeyup="getalias(this)">
<input id="alias" type="text" name="txtalias">
```

Comment: thank you, this is enough. whether this be in the limit just like 3 or 4 word for the alias?

Comment: A simple if condition would help..set the length of array after we split it..or just dont generate alias if the length of the input value is greater than your limit constant..